# Python Kivy. My program should append the textfile, but is does not

Tags: python, kivy

Textfile should look like this :

e.g

```
Walking 61.0/2018-09-04 79.0/2018-10-04   
Running 24.0/2018-09-04 33.0/2018-10-04
```

The point of this function is to append the textfile with the new value of the slider or to change one.

There are some names for the slider and each of them can have many values which consist of a slider.value and the current date. If today is not the date of the last value - then we append the file.

If today is the same date as the date of the last value - then it is supposed to change it(I did not do it yet, but this is not a problem, i will do it myself after I solve this problem).

Here is the full Python file and Kivy files, nothing but def save_values matters. Everything else is just to make the program working for you.

Python

```
from kivy.app import App

import time
import datetime


from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

from kivy.config import Config

screen_width = 450
screen_height = 800

Config.set("graphics", "resizable","1")
Config.set("graphics", "width", screen_width)

Config.set("graphics", "height", screen_height)

languages = ["Reading","Writing","Running","Climbing"]
spawned_List = ["False"]


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class JobChoiceScreen(Screen):
    def changing_screen(self, instance, *args):
        self.manager.current= "sliderScreen"

        screenSlider = self.manager.get_screen('sliderScreen')
        text = str(instance.text)

        screenSlider.changing_label(text)

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        if spawned_List[0] == "False":
            for x in range(0,len(languages)):
                word = languages[x]
                word = str(word)
                btn = Button(text = word, size_hint=(None, None), size = (140,70),
                font_size = 18, bold = True, color = [0,1,1,1], background_color = (.156, .172, .24, 0.7),
                on_release = self.changing_screen)

                self.ids.container.add_widget(btn)

                spawned_List[0] = "True"

            self.ids.boxLayBottom.add_widget(Widget(size_hint=(1, .4)))

            self.ids.datesContainer.add_widget(Button(text = "Day back", size_hint=(.28, 1), font_size = 18, bold = True, color = [0,1,1,1], background_color = (.176, .192, .44, 0.7)))
            self.ids.datesContainer.add_widget(Widget(size_hint=(.44, 1)))
            self.ids.datesContainer.add_widget(Button(text = "Day forward", size_hint=(.28, 1), font_size = 18, bold = True, color = [0,1,1,1], background_color = (.176, .192, .44, 0.7)))

class SliderScreen(Screen):


    def save_values(self, *args, **kwargs):
        date = (datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d"))
        written = (str(self.ids.my_slider.value)+ "/" + date + " ")
        print("started save_values")

        with open('values.txt', 'r') as fileValues:
            lines = fileValues.readlines()
            print("opened the file")

            with open('values.txt', 'a') as fileValues:
                for i, line in enumerate(lines):
                    if line.startswith(self.ids.my_label.text) and line.find(date) == -1:
                        line = line + ((self.ids.my_label.text) + " " + written)
                        print(line)

                        if not line.startswith(self.ids.my_label.text) and line.find(date) == -1:
                            line = (" " + written)
                            print(line)
                            print("hello bill")

    def changing_label(self, text):
        self.ids.my_label.text = text


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("manager.kv")

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Kivy

```
ScreenManagement:
    #transition: FadeTransition()
    MenuScreen:
    JobChoiceScreen:
    SliderScreen:

<MenuScreen>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source:"background.jpg"
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    name: "menu"

    BoxLayout:
        padding: [10,10,10,10]
        orientation: "vertical"
        Widget:
            size_hint: [1,0.2]

        BoxLayout:

            Button:
                bold: True
                color: [0,1,1,1]
                on_release: app.root.current = "list_of_jobs"
                text: "Change"
                size_hint: [0.28,1]
                font_size: 20
                background_color: (.156, .172, .24, 0.7)

            Widget:
                size_hint: [0.44,1]

            Button:
                bold: True
                color: [.5,0, .8, .7]
                text: "View \n Progress"
                size_hint: [0.28,1]         
                font_size: 20
                halign: "center" 
                valign: "center"
                background_color: (.156, .172, .24, 0.7)
                on_release: app.root.current = "sliderScreen"

        Widget:
            size_hint: [1,0.2]


<JobChoiceScreen>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source:"background.jpg"
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    name: "list_of_jobs"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: [10,10,10,10]
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            id: boxLayBottom
            size_hint: (1,.1)

            BoxLayout:
                id: datesContainer
                orientation: "horizontal"
                size_hint: (1,.6)
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: "center"
            acnhor_y: "top"
            size_hint: (1,.8)

            GridLayout:
                id: container
                cols: 3
                spacing: 5

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            id: boxContainer
            size_hint: (1,.1)

            Button:
                text: "Back to Menu" 
                on_release: app.root.current = "menu"
                bold: True
                color: [0,1,1,1]
                background_color: (.176, .192, .44, 0.7)

<SliderScreen>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source:"background.jpg"
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    name: "sliderScreen"

    BoxLayout:
        padding: [10,10,10,10]
        orientation: "vertical"
        id: my_label_container

        Slider: 
            id: my_slider
            min: 0
            max: 100
            value: 0
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint: [1, 0.7]
            step: 1

        Label: 
            id: my_label
            size_hint: [1, 0.2]
            bold: True
            font_size: 40
            text: ""

        Button:
            size_hint: [1, 0.1]
            bold: True
            on_release: app.root.current = "menu"
            text : "Back Home"
            font_size: 20
            halign: "center" 
            valign: "center"
            background_color: (.156, .172, .24, 0.7)
            on_press: root.save_values()
```

def save_values

```
def save_values(self, *args, **kwargs):
    date = (datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d"))
    written = (str(self.ids.my_slider.value)+ "/" + date + " ")
    print("started save_values")

    with open('values.txt', 'r') as fileValues:
        lines = fileValues.readlines()
        print("opened the file")

        with open('values.txt', 'a') as fileValues:
            for i, line in enumerate(lines):
                if line.startswith(self.ids.my_label.text) and line.find(date) == -1:
                    line = line + ((self.ids.my_label.text) + " " + written)
                    print(line)

                    if not line.startswith(self.ids.my_label.text) and line.find(date) == -1:
                        line = (" " + written)
                        print(line)
                        print("hello bill")
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your code:

1. In your `save_values()` method, You are opening the `values.txt` file twice at the same time with the same name, but with different modes. I think you need to unindent the second `with open` block, remove the second `with open` statement, and modify the mode in the first `with open` statement to `r+`. So your code should look something like:

   ```
   with open('values.txt', 'r+') as fileValues:
       lines = fileValues.readlines()
       print("opened the file")

       for i, line in enumerate(lines):
   ```
2. You never call any `write` routine, so nothing gets written. When you want to append line/lines to `values.txt`, you need to call `fileValues.write()` or `fileValues.writelines()`.

I have not looked at your code logic, so I will not comment on that.